# Import multiple python function from different program in STAX Job

Tags: testing, automation, stax, python-2.5, staf

I have been working on STAF & STAX. I have created a STAX job using some modules of python and multiple functions, but all of them are in the same file.

Now I want to create a big STAX job using multiple python programs, and different functions from each program.

How can I *import or include* multiple functions, from different programs stored in different files, in a single STAX JOB?

**Ex:**

```
<stax>
<script> function5_add from file1.py </script>
.
.
.
<script> function2_sub from file2.py </script>
.
.
.
<script> function1_mul from file5.py </script>
.
.
.
<script> all n function from file6.py </script>

<stax>
```

Any help??

How can I use the Conditional Import of a function in a STAX job?